# Adding text in the middle of a sentence in PowerPoint using interop

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, office-addins

I have written some simple code that adds a textbox, some text and style. The texbox I've added says "This is my new text". Somewhere in the middle of this textbox I want to add another piece of text saying "more text", for example "this is my more text new text". I'm not sure how I could achieve this as I'm fairly new to working with interop and I'm not even sure if it possible.

My code is as follows:

```
Application pptApplication = new Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shp;
Font2 font2;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;

TextRange2 objText2;

// Create the Presentation File
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(@"C:\Users\Craig\Documents\AddText.pptx");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

// Create new Slide
slides = pptPresentation.Slides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide firstSlide = Globals.ThisAddIn
    .Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1];
shp= firstSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left: 30, Top: 30, Width:340, Height: 340);

shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "This is my new text";
shp.TextEffect.FontName = "Arial";
shp.TextEffect.FontSize = 32;

pptPresentation.Save();
```

Comment: You should really use more usings to make your code more readable, e.g., `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`. Also, why do you declare the variables all at the top, e.g., `slides` you could declare right after your comment "Create new Slide".

Comment: This code is just in my text project that's why it's a bit messy

Comment: You will not save time - ever - by writing messy code. My advice would be to try and get the habit of writing clean code always. You will get as fast or even faster in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. I haven't tested this code specifically, but I've been doing other things in PowerPoint interop lately and this is working for me.

```
shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "This is my new text";
var start = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find("This is my ");
start.InsertAfter("more text ");
```